# Еще раз про ссылки

Tags: gcc, ссылки, c++

Еще один глупый вопрос по C++/ Имеется следующий код:

```
int ival = 1;
int& ival2 = ival;
int&* prval1 = &ival2;
```

при попытке это скомпилировать получаю ошибку:

> error: cannot declare pointer to 'int&

Вопрос:  почему же я не могу объявить указатель на ссылку на int?

Comment: Можно объявить ссылку на указатель.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у ссылки нет адреса.

Answer (score 2):

Ссылка, по сути - та же переменная, на которую она ссылается. Похоже на синоним к имени этой переменной, только вот ссылаться на адрес памяти ссылки ты не можешь, т.к. у той ограничение на ее использование. Ведь обращаясь к ссылке, ты же меняешь саму переменную, а не ее.